# C# silverlight application server

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am building an application that needs to connect to a server to send and retrieve data constantly.

at first i was going to use mysql, by mysql is far from what i want. using this would force users to connect to the database constantly.

CAN C# silverlight connect to a server and send a message?

here is an example to something in C# console, VERY similar to what i am trying to achieve
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9kcrTKj7Jpk

Any documentation would also be helpful.
To be more specific my server will be written with C# console, but i want my c# silverlight to send the message.

Comment: MySQL is a database, not a transport mechanism.

Comment: Why would using MySQL 'force users to connect to the database constantly'? - and it you need to send and receive data 'constantly' why would that be bad? Why would Silverlight make it better? I don't understand the problem here.

Comment: Im writting the application in silverlight regardless if i were to use MYSQL. having 100k users retrieve data from a database continuously every 1/2 second would stress the server dramatically. The best course of action would be to use a server & client for what i am trying to achieve.

Comment: All i need to know is, can silverlight send to a server?

Comment: @user3466723 [Yes it can.](http://www.netflix.com/WiHome)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

> CAN C# silverlight connect to a server and send a message?

Traditionally, the way that Silverlight has connected to a server to send a message is with WCF services. This still works well, but the other option is REST.

What you will need to do is write a layer (or use an ORM like Entity Framework) to persist data from whichever database platform you choose (MySQL or otherwise). Then you will need to write REST, or WCF services on top of this. You will then need to consume the services from your Silverlight application.

There are many articles on this if you Google. Here is one of the ones that comes up instantly:
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=228

One thing you must consider with Silverlight, is that by default, Silverlight will only talk to the server that the Xap package is hosted on. So, if you need the Silverlight app to talk to a different server, you will need to set up and expose a clientaccesspolixy.xml from the server where the WCF/REST services are hosted. This is a stupid limitation that Microsoft made a big mistake on in the first place. Here is an article about it:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/cc197955(v=vs.95).aspx